# Avoiding the overheads of std::function

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, std-function

I want to run a set of operations over elements in a (custom) singly-linked list. The code to traverse the linked list and run the operations is simple, but repetitive and could be done wrong if copy/pasted everywhere. Performance & careful memory allocation is important in my program, so I want to avoid unnecessary overheads.

I want to write a wrapper to include the repetitive code and encapsulate the operations which are to take place on each element of the linked list. As the functions which take place within the operation vary I need to capture multiple variables (in the real code) which must be provided to the operation, so I looked at using `std::function`. The actual calculations done in this example code are meaningless here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
  explicit Foo(int num) : variable(num) {}
  int variable;
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> next;
};

void doStuff(Foo& foo, std::function<void(Foo&)> operation)
{
  Foo* fooPtr = &foo;
  do
  {
    operation(*fooPtr);
  } while (fooPtr->next && (fooPtr = fooPtr->next.get()));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int val = 7;
  Foo first(4);
  first.next = std::make_unique<Foo>(5);
  first.next->next = std::make_unique<Foo>(6);
#ifdef USE_FUNC
  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
  {
    doStuff(first, [&](Foo& foo){ foo.variable += val + i; /*Other, more complex functionality here */ });
  }
  doStuff(first, [&](Foo& foo){ std::cout << foo.variable << std::endl; /*Other, more complex and different functionality here */ });
#else
  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
  {
    Foo* fooPtr = &first;
    do
    {
      fooPtr->variable += val + i;
    } while (fooPtr->next && (fooPtr = fooPtr->next.get()));
  }
  Foo* fooPtr = &first;
  do
  {
    std::cout << fooPtr->variable << std::endl;
  } while (fooPtr->next && (fooPtr = fooPtr->next.get()));
#endif
}
```

If run as:

```
g++ test.cpp -O3 -Wall -o mytest && time ./mytest
1587459716
1587459717
1587459718

real    0m0.252s
user    0m0.250s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Whereas if run as:

```
g++ test.cpp -O3 -Wall -DUSE_FUNC -o mytest && time ./mytest 
1587459716
1587459717
1587459718

real    0m0.834s
user    0m0.831s
sys 0m0.001s
```

These timings are fairly consistent across multiple runs, and show a 4x multiplier when using `std::function`. Is there a better way I can do what I want to do?

Comment: Do all the functions have the same signature? Same body/captures?

Comment: Make `doStuff` a template that accepts an arbitrary functor. (You can't hide the definition from other translation units in that case, but that's the price to pay for compile-time encapsulation).

Comment: @vittorio Unfortunately not, each of the operations done has different arguments passed into it.

Comment: If performance is important, I would first replace linked list with a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a template:

```
template<typename T>
void doStuff(Foo& foo, T const& operation)
```

For me this gives:

```
mvine@xxx:~/mikeytemp$ g++ test.cpp -O3 -DUSE_FUNC -std=c++14 -Wall -o mytest && time ./mytest
1587459716
1587459717
1587459718

real    0m0.534s
user    0m0.529s
sys     0m0.005s
mvine@xxx:~/mikeytemp$ g++ test.cpp -O3 -std=c++14 -Wall -o mytest && time ./mytest
1587459716
1587459717
1587459718

real    0m0.583s
user    0m0.583s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that's a neat solution. Did you just replace the definition of doStuff with the code you quoted? When I do that I get: `real 0m0.333s`, a ~30% increase over copy/pasting.

Comment: Literally the only 2 lines I changed

Comment: In which case you probably want to go look at the generated asm and see if there's a difference. You _should_ find that the generated code is pretty much the same.

Comment: `T const&` here can cause some problems (introduces limitation on T), it is better to use `T` or `T &&`.

Comment: @MikeVine I uploaded to https://godbolt.org/z/ATicIf and there are some differences, but unfortunately my assembly is too limited to understand what the differences mean. It's interesting that they are so close though, due to the optimisation as you suggest.

Comment: Right, looking at that code its basically exactly the same, except for the jmp just before `.L35`.

Comment: And that jump is infact the same, but on the Righthand side its decided to put it down at the bottom (L55 on the right) so there is literally no meaningful difference. Which is pretty much what I got. Why you are getting something different I dont know - is your g++ up todate, etc?

Answer (score 6):

Function objects are quite heavy weight, but have a use where the payload is quite large (>10000 cycles) or needs to be polymorphic such as in a generalised job scheduler.

They need to contain a copy of your callable object and handle any exceptions it might throw.

Using a template gets you much closer to the metal as the resulting code frequently gets inlined.

```
template <typename Func>
void doStuff(Foo& foo, Func operation)
{
  Foo* fooPtr = &foo;
  do
  {
    operation(*fooPtr);
  } while (fooPtr->next && (fooPtr = fooPtr->next.get()));
}
```

The compiler will be able to look inside your function and eliminate redundancy.

On Golbolt, your inner loop becomes

```
.LBB0_6:                                # =>This Loop Header: Depth=1
        lea     edx, [rax + 7]
        mov     rsi, rcx
.LBB0_7:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_6 Depth=1
        add     dword ptr [rsi], edx
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rsi + 8]
        test    rsi, rsi
        jne     .LBB0_7
        mov     esi, eax
        or      esi, 1
        add     esi, 7
        mov     rdx, rcx
.LBB0_9:                                #   Parent Loop BB0_6 Depth=1
        add     dword ptr [rdx], esi
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [rdx + 8]
        test    rdx, rdx
        jne     .LBB0_9
        add     rax, 2
        cmp     rax, 100000000
        jne     .LBB0_6
```

As a bonus, if you didn't use a linked list, the loop may disappear entirely.